# Equivalent to Windows Live Writer for Linux?

Tags: linux, wordpress, blogging, windows-live-writer

Is there any Linux equivalent to Windows Live Writer? I've got the Wordpress for iPhone app  on my iPod and Windows Live Writer on Windows. These programs are much easier for stuff such as adding images than the web interface. Is there a similar program for Linux that works with self-hosted Wordpress blogs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a similar product with **all** of the features, but [Gnome Blog](http://www.gnome.org/~seth/gnome-blog/) is pretty cool. It's very simple to use and works right from the panel:

[image]

> Features:
>
> - Clean interface doesn't get in the way of what you're writing
> - WYSIWYG styled text support
> - Entries can be written gradually over the course of a day, popping
>     gnome blog open and closed as you have
>     thoughts to jot down and then posting
>     at the end of the day
> - Operates as a panel object/applet or a standalone application
> - Supports many different kinds of blogs
> - **New** Spell checking
> - **New** Drag and drop images into your blog entry (if your blog supports it)
>
> Supported Blogs:
>
> - Blogger.com / Blogspot.com
> - Advogato.org
> - Movable Type
> - **New** WordPress
> - **New** LiveJournal.com
> - Pyblosxom
> - Any other blog using bloggerAPI or MetaWeblog